# Download Lubuntu iso with the last updates included into it

Tags: lubuntu

Can someone say please, where is it possible to find to download from an official source, the Lubuntu iso with the last updates included into it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the current daily iso files from the iso testing tracker, which is used by us who are testing Ubuntu and the Ubuntu community flavours.

[ISO Testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/)

Specifically you can find daily iso files for 16.04 LTS "Xenial", and 18.04 LTS "Bionic" and soon also for "CC" to be released as 18.10 in October.